# Transaction isolation level on an oledb-connection

Tags: sql-server-2005, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I have an oledb-connection from clickview to a sql2005-server and I would like this connection to use transaction isolation level of read uncommitted.  My seconde choice would be to set it on the user. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709786(VS.85).aspx

When you starts transaction by ITransactionLocal::StartTransaction you explicitly need specify isolation level.